# Install and run a second copy of app

Tags: installation

There are many apps which install too `%AppData%` If I need to install a second copy I have to create a new local user (This step is needed only once), run the installer as the second user and every time I need to run the app run it as a second user.

Is there an easier way to do this or an app which automates the process?

Comment: For many apps you can also install a portable version (which doesn't write at all to the registry).

Comment: This feels a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you shouldn't ever need a second copy, as the same code can run multiple times. However, if the App explicitly checks for already running instances, and then attaches to the running instance instead of starting a new one, there is nothing you can do about it. It wouldn't matter *where* you install it to, the behavior woud be the same.

Your workaround with different users works because the app is not authorized to see the instance running under the other user. For that to work, you need multiple user IDs, but *not* multiple installations - simply install once as admin, then run multiple instances under multiple users.